# Is there a way to find unused expectations in jMock?

Tags: java, jmock, expectations

We use jMock for a lot of our Java tests. In some test classes, most of the tests work the same way, so common expectations end up in a `setUp()` method.

Quite often, some of the expectations in the `setUp()` method are only used for some of the tests. So all these expectations tend to be `allowing()` types which don't require being called every test.

Now, sometimes code internal to the system changes in a way which removes an expectation. For instance, maybe a deprecated API call gets replaced with a non-deprecated one. But these expectations continue to succeed because they don't require at least one call. As far as I know, there is no way to say "require at least one call across this entire test class", and it's a different instance of `Mockery` every time anyway, so that would never work.

Nonetheless, it would be nice if I had a way to track these down and automatically delete them.

I figure I could do it manually... Delete a line at random -> See if the tests still pass -> If they pass, commit, otherwise revert -> Repeat.

But is there an automatic way? (Other than obviously writing my own tool to automate the manual process.)